# Add Formatting To Custom File Association

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have an extension installed to add custom handling of a HTML/CSS/JS environment that has custom features for the Sciter UI library. However, this extension requires me to associate the file types I want to use the custom sciter verions of things, such as:

```
"files.associations": {
    "*.scs": "sciter-css",
    "*.shtm": "sciter-html",
    "*.shtml": "sciter-html"
},
```

While the majority of things are normal HTML, there are some special features that are added in the extensions language files.

Is there a way for me to use these custom associations but still have the ability to use the built-in / default HTML formatting when I tell VSCode to format the document? (Same for CSS, and JS.)

Comment: My answer refers to the general problem, but in this specific case, what features are you wanting from the extension? From what I see, the extension contributes syntax highlighting and snippets. The snippets could easily be pulled out and added to your user snippets for  html. How different is the highlighting?

Comment: Sciter implements a handful of custom HTML/CSS/JS features that are not standard or follow any of the standards exactly, so a handful of things result in VSCode giving errors in documents based on Sciter syntax if I use just normal HTML/CSS/JS handling. Snippets is not something I personally use. Just the syntax highlighting is all I need from the extension. But I would l like to have the formatting features of the stock HTML/CSS/JS file engines as well.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your problem a bit more now. I have added more information to my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:**

Based on the information I'm hearing from you, you might be able to use the [beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HookyQR.beautify) extension with these settings in your user or workspace settings:

```
{
  "beautify.language": {
    "js": ["js", "json", "tiscript"]
    "css": ["css", "scss", "sciter-css"],
    "html": ["htm", "html", "sciter-html"]
    // ^^ providing just an array sets the VS Code file type
  }
}
```

**End Edit**

As a general answer, unfortunately no.

There can only be one active "language" for a document. Though there is a discussion [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/22415) about allowing multiple languages.

The extension author either needs to add their features to the existing `html`, `javascript`, and `CSS` languages, or the developer themselves need to add the basic functionality for those languages.

Also, instead of using a language ID at all, the extension author could also provide functionality based on the file extensions directly and allow the user to provide a different set of file extensions in the settings if they need them.

Comment: Thanks for this Llewey does what I need. :) One last question about this kind of setup. VSCode offers the hotkey to format a document. Is there a way to bind beautify to that hotkey as well with the original hotkeys purpose to format documents by default?

Comment: Actually, the extension macros does exactly what I need for the hotkey setup. Thanks again Llewey!